# Reporting AWS Tools RDS or Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, relational-database, amazon-redshift, analytics, amazon-rds

Let me start - I have situation where my app is doing more of reporting stuff like dashboards, filters, based on filters forecast/sales etc data have to be shown. we decided to build the UI with Angular or similar UI. this is going to be in AWS cloud. So, when it comes to back end we are having confusion what tools should we be using it? Would RDS fit the bill here? our application is more of read heavy (hardly any updates/deletes) and every read has to prform analytics on the data. Also, the set of tables not more than 10-15 and also the rows isnt huge I would say. like each table may have at max .3 million rows.

with this background - what would be the right fit for back end perspective? we are contemplating between RDS (any Oracle/SQL) and RedShift. with the size of data that we have (it may grow in future but not exceptionally) is Redshift is going to be overkill? RDS could be a right fit but due to heavy analytics that we (calculations/aggregations etc)?

On the first instance we may have to load the data from S3 data files - we are still thinknig how to load that data possibly Redshift Spectrum.

btw, we are planning to use AWS Lambda as middle-ware to fetch data for UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if an Amazon RDS database is sufficient for your needs, then it is preferable over using Amazon Redshift. Therefore, start with RDS and see how it goes!

More specifically:

- Amazon RDS is better for **transactions** (updating a small number of items in a database)
- Amazon Redshift is better for tables with **millions and billions of rows** (for reporting queries, not so much for small updates)
- If you're going to use Amazon RDS, consider using **Amazon Aurora** since it has excellent performance, reliability, scaling, etc
- Use an **open-source engine** if possible (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB) rather than a proprietary engine to lower costs and reduce lock-in

Comment: Thanks for your response. we set to go with Redshift with reason of being not many update/inserts to db its more of reads and analytics.

Comment: From a cost perspective, Amazon RDS might be a lower cost, but it really depends upon whether it has the required performance. If possible, try them both and do some comparisons. For Amazon RDS, indexing tables is important. For Amazon Redshift, selecting the best Distribution Key and Sort Key for each table is most important.